# How do you split a time series into separate events and assign an event ID?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I want split an irregular time series into separate events and assign each event a unique numerical ID for each site.

Here is an example data frame:

```
structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AllenBrook", "Eastberk"), class = 
"factor"), 
    timestamp = structure(c(10L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
    11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("10/1/12 11:29", "10/1/12 14:29", 
    "10/1/12 17:29", "10/20/12 16:30", "10/20/12 19:30", "10/21/12 1:30", 
    "10/21/12 4:30", "9/5/12 12:30", "9/5/12 4:14", "9/5/12 6:30", 
    "9/5/12 7:14", "9/5/12 7:44", "9/5/12 9:30"), class = "factor")), class 
= "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Each event is not the same length or number of timestamps, so I want to split them into separate events if more than 12 hours elapsed between a timestamp and the next timestamp at that site. Each event at the site should receive a unique numerical ID. Here's the outcome I would like:

```
         site      timestamp eventid
1  AllenBrook    9/5/12 6:30       1
2  AllenBrook    9/5/12 9:30       1
3  AllenBrook   9/5/12 12:30       1
4  AllenBrook 10/20/12 16:30       2
5  AllenBrook 10/20/12 19:30       2
6  AllenBrook  10/21/12 1:30       2
7  AllenBrook  10/21/12 4:30       2
8    Eastberk    9/5/12 4:14       1
9    Eastberk    9/5/12 7:14       1
10   Eastberk    9/5/12 7:44       1
11   Eastberk  10/1/12 11:29       2
12   Eastberk  10/1/12 14:29       2
13   Eastberk  10/1/12 17:29       2
```

Any coding solution will do, but bonus points for a `tidyverse` or `data.table` solution. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`, you can perhaps do the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tmp)[, timestamp := as.POSIXct(timestamp, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")][, 
    eventid := 1L+cumsum(c(0L, diff(timestamp)>720)), by=.(site)]
```

`diff(timestamp)` calculates the time difference between adjacent rows. Then we check if the diff is greater than 12h (or 720mins). A common trick in R is to use `cumsum` to identify when an event happens in a series and group subsequent elements together with this event until the next event happens again. Since `cumsum` returns 1 less element, we use 0L to pad the beginning. `1+` merely starts the indexing from 1 instead of 0.

output:

```
          site           timestamp eventid
 1: AllenBrook 2012-09-05 06:30:00       1
 2: AllenBrook 2012-09-05 09:30:00       1
 3: AllenBrook 2012-09-05 12:30:00       1
 4: AllenBrook 2012-10-20 16:30:00       2
 5: AllenBrook 2012-10-20 19:30:00       2
 6: AllenBrook 2012-10-21 01:30:00       2
 7: AllenBrook 2012-10-21 04:30:00       2
 8:   Eastberk 2012-09-05 04:14:00       1
 9:   Eastberk 2012-09-05 07:14:00       1
10:   Eastberk 2012-09-05 07:44:00       1
11:   Eastberk 2012-10-01 11:29:00       2
12:   Eastberk 2012-10-01 14:29:00       2
13:   Eastberk 2012-10-01 17:29:00       2
```

data:

```
tmp <- structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AllenBrook", "Eastberk"), class = 
     "factor"), 
 timestamp = structure(c(10L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
     11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("10/1/12 11:29", "10/1/12 14:29", 
         "10/1/12 17:29", "10/20/12 16:30", "10/20/12 19:30", "10/21/12 1:30", 
         "10/21/12 4:30", "9/5/12 12:30", "9/5/12 4:14", "9/5/12 6:30", 
         "9/5/12 7:14", "9/5/12 7:44", "9/5/12 9:30"), class = "factor")), class 
 = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
     -13L))
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! Any chance you could describe in plain language how this works? eventid := 1L+cumsum(c(0L, diff(timestamp)>720))?

Comment: added some explanation. try running in the console and see it for yourself. `x <- diff(c(1,2,3,6,7,8,11,12,12)) > 2` and `cumsum(c(0, x))`